# Image within TD element

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a table with JavaScript.

Issue I am facing with the last column with image
Have used display=block and height=10%
But the two images comes in different size and exploding beyond normal height of the cell
Any help?
Image link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-erVHxfjF5MSllSUi1UZWNKeVU

Code:

```
TD = document.createElement("TD");
TD.style.borderWidth="1px";
TD.style.borderStyle="none none inset none";
TD.style.borderColor="#54514e";
TD.style.textAlign="center";
/*
tForTD=document.createTextNode("submit");
*/
tForTD = document.createElement("IMG");
tForTD.setAttribute("src", "Img/submit_2.png");
tForTD.style.backgroundColor="white";
/*
tForTD.style.position="absolute";
tForTD.style.top="0%";
tForTD.style.display="block";
*/
tForTD.style.height="10%";
tForTD.style.borderRadius="50%";
tForTD.style.filter="grayscale(80%)";
tForTD.style.boxShadow="0px 1px 3px 0px black";
/*
tForTD.onclick=  ( function(index) {
return function() { OnClickAddBill(index); };
} )(i);
*/
TD.appendChild(tForTD);
TR.appendChild(TD);
DBT.appendChild(TR);
```

Comment: Add markup/code, current output and expected output.

Comment: Please provide your code and links to the images you're talking about. That will make helping you much easier.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: I want second and third row to have exactly same height as that of header row

Answer (score 0):

To fit the img inside block add a class like `img-fit`:

```
.img-fit {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Also, try to use 10vh instead of 10%:

> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport

```css
td {
  height: 10vh;
}

.img-fit {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td><img class="img-fit" src="http://placehold.it/350x350">111</td>
  <td><img class="img-fit" src="http://placehold.it/350x350">222</td>
</table>
```

Comment: have tried tForTD.style.maxHeight="50%"; but not working; omly works with tForTD.style.maxWidth="50%"; but i need to restrict the height

Comment: @MrC `<table>` is kind tricky, if you are sure about height, use like 50px maybe?

Comment: I am not sure about height unfortunately :(

Comment: One thing I am confused : why maxWidth is working but not maxHeight?

Comment: @MrC to use % heigh, you need to have the height defined, maybe try to use `vh`?